# Guaranteeing object reuse while copying an object in Java

Tags: android, garbage-collection, jvm, immutability

In the following code we rotate a complex number by some angle in a loop and then confirm that the resulting number is identical to the one we started with.

```
public class Complex {
    private float r, i;
    ...
    public Complex(Complex other) {
        r = other.r;
        i = other.i;
    }

}

Complex z1 = new Complex(..);
Complex z1_save = new Complex(z1);
Complex z2 = new Complex();
Complex k = new Complex();
k.set_to_first_root_of_unity(8);
int n = 64;
while(n-- != 0) {
    z1.multiply(k, z2);
    z1 = new Complex(z2); // Line Y
}
Assert.assertEquals(true, z1.equals(z1_save));
```

Is there a way in Java to write Line Y using the constructor `public Complex(Complex other)` rather than `clone()`, and be certain that 64 objects will not be garbage collected?

**Update:**  It seems it is impossible to ask this question in a simplified manner without referring to the context—that of an interactive application. The best answer to the present question so far (assylias's) is that one should not worry about object creation and garbage collection 90% of the time. During redraw, it is necessary to worry about it 100% of the time. I have now restated the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505775/should-one-delay-side-effects-in-an-interactive-application-on-android).

Comment: Foo was the name of the class before I made the question more concrete. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: If it is a different object it is a different object. Anyway, the GC won't free anything that you can access, so you should not worry about that possibility.

Comment: I'm not worried about accessing something that has been GCed. I am worried about the inefficiency of the GC running 64 times unnecessarily.

Comment: The GC won't run each time an object is dereferenced. The JVM will fire it when it likes, and the GC will collect what it deems worth the effort.

Comment: The question is whether it is possible to avoid using clone() (which is not used in the code).

Comment: "The question is wheter it is possible to avoid using X, which is not used". It is some sort of logical paradox? I think there is some other site for that kind of questions...

Comment: you really should clean up this example - it could be *much* simpler and still demonstrate the issue

Comment: @TomCarchrae Well, I thought that a real (or complex!) example is nicer than yet another foo-bar -based question. YMMV.

Comment: @SJuan76 In other words: X is not used. I know we can solve the problem if we were to use X. Can the problem be solved while continuing not to use X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am worried about the inefficiency of the GC running 64 times unnecessarily.

That is an unnecessary worry. If your objects are in the young generation (which they will considering their scope) GC will be free (as in 0 cost).

When the GC runs on the young generation, it only goes through live objects (objects that are eligible for GC are not visited), so the GC time is a function of the live objects only.

The story is different for the old generation, but your local objects won't reach that stage.

Reference - [Brian Goetz](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp09275/index.html), emphasis mine:

> **What about deallocation?**
>
> But allocation is only half of memory management -- deallocation is the other half. It turns out that for most objects, the direct garbage collection cost is -- zero. This is because a copying collector does not need to visit or copy dead objects, only live ones. So objects that become garbage shortly after allocation contribute no workload to the collection cycle.
>
> ?It turns out that the vast majority of objects in typical object-oriented programs (between 92 and 98 percent according to various studies) "die young," which means they become garbage shortly after they are allocated, often before the next garbage collection. (This property is called the generational hypothesis and has been empirically tested and found to be true for many object-oriented languages.) **Therefore, not only is allocation fast, but for most objects, deallocation is free.**

Comment: Interesting... Does this mean that we would have the likelihood, but not the certainty, that the object z1 will be reused at each iteration of Line Y? Also, do you agree with the comment that "z1.multiply(k, z2)" is poor style due to the side effect? How would you write it? Its intention is precisely to avoid creating an object if we were to write instead "z2 = z1.multiply(k)".

Comment: You should forget about avoiding creating objects: (i) it is mostly free (object creation is less than 10 CPU cycles and GC of local variables is free) and (ii) the JVM will optimise your code IF it is written in a standard way - in your case it might reuse the space in memory (or not if is not more efficient). To help the JVM, your best bet is to use standard idioms (have a look at BigDecimal for example): `z2 = z1.multiply(k);`.

Comment: Once your code works AND you determine that there is a memory/performance issue AND it is linked to that portion of code THEN you can start to try to optimise that portion of code. My guess is that those conditions won't be met.

Answer (score 1):

Executing constructor 64 times for an object with ten (or so) fields is not a big deal even for a device like a cell phone.

It is not clear what your task is.

If you are really concerned about calling constructor many times and creating too many identical object, you may try to use the Flightweight pattern.

Comment: It's a question of principle, not of 64 times on a cell phone. How can one avoid unnecessary object construction (while keeping the code legible)?

Comment: There are many ways to do it, one way - using flightweight pattern, another one - not using objects at all (instead - using operations with primitives). There is no general answer. it depends on the situation.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate? I don't see how the Flyweight pattern relates to this example.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Your question (and comments) are a bit confused ... but that might just be a problem with your written English skills.  So I'm just assuming I understand what you *meant* to say.  I'm also assuming that your example "works" ... which it currently doesn't.</sup>

The short answer is that you can reduce object churn (i.e. creation and release of "temporary" objects) by making your `Complex` object mutable.  Typically you do this by adding setter operations that allow you to change the state of the object.  But that has the effect of making your `Complex` class more difficult to use correctly.  For example:

```
    public static final ZERO = new Complex(0, 0);

    // somewhere else

    Complex counter = ZERO;
    while (counter.lessThan(10)) {
        // ....
        counter.setRealPart(counter.getRealPart() + 1);  // Ooops!!
    }
```

... and lots more bugs like that.

Then there is the question of whether this will actually reduce garbage collection overheads, and by how much.

As @assylias points out, temporary objects that are created and then reclaimed in the next GC cycle have very low cost.  The objects that are expensive are the ones that DON'T become garbage.  And it is quite possible that for a normal program running in a normal environment, it is actually *more efficient* overall to create temporary objects.

Then there is the issue that the latest HotSpot JVMs can do something known as "escape analysis", which (if it works) can determine that a given temporary object will never be visible outside of its creation scope, and therefore doesn't need to be allocated in the heap at all.  When that optimization can be applied, the "object churn" concern is mooted.

However, running the GC can be bad for "real time" performance; e.g. in games programming, where the user will notice if the game freezes for a fraction of a second.  In cases like that, it is worth considering "tuning" your code to reduce object churn.  But there are other possible approaches too ... like using a low-pause garbage collector ... if one is available for your platform.

---

@assylias's comment makes another important.  Beware of *premature* optimization.  Your intuition on the usage of your `Complex` object ... and the resulting object churn ... could be *very* wrong.  All things being equal, it is best to delay optimization effort until you have profiled the application and determined that:

- it *needs* to be tuned, and
- the profiling evidence points to the `Complex` class being a significant performance bottleneck.

Comment: I had not envisaged the real time issue. As you point out, on the one hand you don't want too frequent GC => don't create too many objects, but on the other hand you don't want too many long-lived objects because GC time will be a function of their number. It is a fine balance to find which can only be achieved through meticulous testing and profiling.

Comment: @StephenC But of course! I welcome critiques of both my Java and my "English skills". If you find one, however mild, syntactic inaccuracy in what I wrote, I'd much appreciate your pointing it out—English included.

Comment: @Calaf - I wasn't talking about grammar.  I was talking about statements like *"I am worried about the inefficiency of the GC running 64 times unnecessarily."* ... and assuming (perhaps incorrectly) that you just didn't express yourself clearly.  But frankly, there's not a lot of point since you don't seem interested in correcting the question.

Comment: @StephenC I see. You're right. It would have been more accurate to write "I am worried that the GC would deallocate 64 objects unnecessarily". As it is it suggests that I am expecting (or could even determine) the number of times that the GC will choose to run, if at all.

Comment: I missed (or you added later) the "But frankly.." part. What changes are you suggesting?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to pay attention to garbage collection at all, *unless*:

- users (maybe you) perceive performance issues with the application; *and*
- profiling the application demonstrates that garbage collection is the source of the perceived performance issues.

Lacking *both* of these conditions: ignore garbage collection.

This is true of performance tuning in Java in general.  Don't do it unless you've proven there's a real reason for it.

Comment: As a blanket suggestion, the recommendation you mention is fine. But notice that the Android Development Kit (ADT) will not let you get away with as much as MyObject myobj = new MyObject(); while overriding View.onDraw() without giving you a lint warning that this is a bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to be efficient w.r.t GC, minimize your use of new.

So, in your example, you could re-use the variable in "Line Y", and simply set the fields with the new value.  Something like:

```
while(n-- != 0) {
    z1.multiply(k, z2);
    z1.setValue(z2); // Line Y
}
```

where z1.setValue(X) sets the state of the object in the same fashion that the constructor new Complex(x) does.

---

EDIT:  Why is this getting down voted?  I stand by the statement above about reducing the cost of GC by minimizing the use of new.  Yes, I agree in most contexts GC is not a problem - but if your code does call GC frequently, perhaps because your code spends a lot of time in a loop (say a CPU heavy algorithm), then you may well want to reuse objects.

Comment: ps, this example code does not make much sense (or it is doing some horrid side effects to z2).

Comment: *If you want to be efficient w.r.t GC, minimize your use of new.* => that is not true.

Comment: If by "this example code" you mean the line "z1.multiply(k, z2)", then by all means, your critique and improvement to the code is more than welcome.

Comment: Ironically, I dislike the line "z1.setValue(z2);" for the same reason. I find it hopeless to remember whether it is intended to set the value of z1 or that of z2. By comparison, an assignment is wholly unambiguous.

Comment: @Calaf When seeing `z1.set(z2)` one would definitely expect that z2 is unchanged and z1's new value is z2.

Comment: @assylias I see your point. If z1.set_real_part(float x) is unambiguous, then one would expect z1.set(z2) to also be unambiguous.

Comment: @assylias - my comment was *only* referring to GC - if you want to minimize GC then you minimize the use of new.  I agree in 99% of cases, GC performance does not matter - in the 1% where it does (hotspot of code) then object re-use *does* boost performance.  The article you linked to pointed that out.  But I agree, in general, worrying about GC is not needed w/ Java.

Comment: It will reduce the frequency of gc but not necessarily its cost.